# How to order rules in work item field

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015, workitem, tfs-process-template

Is there a way to apply rules in a specific order?

I want to offer YesNo ONLY if two specific values are selected from another field... my rules in XML look like this:

```
  <WHEN field="xxx.yyy.FoundInVersion" value="xxx">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES not="[project]\xxx" expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="No" />
      <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
  <WHEN field="xxx.yyy.FoundInVersion" value="yyy">
    <ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE />
    <ALLOWEDVALUES not="[project]\xxx" expanditems="true">
      <LISTITEM value="No" />
      <LISTITEM value="Yes" />
    </ALLOWEDVALUES>
  </WHEN>
  <ALLOWEDVALUES not="[project]\MigrationAccounts" expanditems="true">
    <LISTITEM value="No" />
  </ALLOWEDVALUES>
```

This works. If either of the both WHENs are correct Yes and No are allowed.

But TFS somehow automatically (on the different/target instance) moves the last ALLOWEDVALUES rule to the top, and only No is allowed and selectable, even if I select one of the values "yyy" or "xxx" in the other field.

It seems to cache somewhere, or try to be intelligent or sth.

How can I force/workaround the rules to my own order?

Answer (score 1):

Rules are typically processed in the sequence in which they are listed. However, when you use the **WHEN***, **DEFAULT**, and **COPY** elements, additional behaviors may apply.

You can gain some idea of how rules are evaluated when you apply multiple rules to a field. **How rules are evaluated is not completely deterministic.** This section describes the expected behavior and interactions when you are using the **WHEN***, **DEFAULT**, and **COPY** rules.

The following steps show, in the correct sequence, the interactions that TFS performs and by the user of a work-item form. Only steps 1, 8, and 13 are performed by the user.

> 1.From a Team Foundation client─such as Visual Studio, Team Explorer, Team Web Access, or Team Explorer Everywhere─, a user creates a new
>   work item or edits an existing work item.
>
> 2.Fill in field defaults. For all fields, use any DEFAULT rules that are outside WHEN* rules.
>
> 3.Copy field values. For all fields, use any COPY rules that are outside WHEN* clauses.
>
> 4.For all fields with a WHEN rule that matches, first do DEFAULT and then COPY rules inside.
>
> 5.For all fields with a WHENNOT rule that matches, first do DEFAULT and then COPY rules inside.
>
> TFS always processes WHEN rules before WHENNOT rules.
>
> 6.For all fields that have had their values changed since step 1 and that contain WHENCHANGED rules, first do DEFAULT and then COPY rules
>   inside.
>
> 7.Allow the user to start editing.
>
> 8.The user changes a field value and then moves focus from the field.
>
> 9.Raise any WHEN rules for that field that match the new value.
>
> 10.Raise any WHENNOT rules for that field that match the new value.
>
> 11.Raise any WHENCHANGED rules for that field that match the new value.
>
> 12.Return editing ability to the user.
>
> 13.The user saves the changes to the database.
>
> 14.For all fields, perform SERVERDEFAULT operations that are defined for the field either directly or indirectly under a WHEN or a WHENNOT
>   rule.